# BacgroundWorkerCompleted does not execute

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Using C# .NET 4.0

I am trying to use a BackgroundWorker to retrieve a list of the services on a remote computer.  This is run as a background worker so the UI remains responsive while waiting for the information.

My approach is to place the request for information in the _DoWork method of the background worker, and use ManualResetEvent.Set() to indicate that the information has been processed.  The ManaualResetEvent should be set in the _RunWorkerCompleted method. _RunWorkerCompleted never executes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DemoTest
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<ServiceController> MyBox1Services;

        ManualResetEvent MyBox1ServicesObtained = new ManualResetEvent(false);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Use background worker to get the list of services in the background
            BackgroundWorker MyBox1Servicess = new BackgroundWorker();
            MyBox1Servicess.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bwGetMyBox1Services_DoWork);
            MyBox1Servicess.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(MyBox1Servicess_RunWorkerCompleted);




            MyBox1Servicess.RunWorkerAsync();

            // Wait until all the services have been obtained before moving on

            MyBox1ServicesObtained.Reset();

            MyBox1ServicesObtained.WaitOne();


            // Update the GUI Here....


        }


        void MyBox1Servicess_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Canceled!");
            }

            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }

            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("MyBox1Servicess_RunWorkerCompleted");
            }
            MyBox1Services = (List<ServiceController>)e.Result;
            MyBox1ServicesObtained.Set();
        }


        void bwGetMyBox1Services_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            ServiceController[] allServices;
            List<ServiceController> allServicesList = new List<ServiceController>();

            try
            {
                allServices = ServiceController.GetServices("MyBox1");
                foreach (ServiceController sc in allServices)
                {
                    allServicesList.Add(sc);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            e.Result = allServicesList;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is firing on the UI thread, which you blocked  in the button click handler with the `ManualResetEvent` call to `WaitOne`.'

Rather than use the `ManualResetEvent`, why not just update your GUI in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler?

Comment: Yes, The ButtonClick handler should complete ASAP

Comment: Thanks. The actual app retrieves services from 10 different servers so I was going to wait for all of them to complete before moving on. (10 MannualResetEvents).  I will find an alternate signaling method.  I probably should use threads instead of a background worker(?)

Comment: @darwin - A Bgw encapsulates a thread. But you should avoid blocking your main (GUI) thread.

Comment: Also, if you're looking to parallelize your work, I'd check into the parallel task library, which would take care of a lot of that synchronization for you.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the error of waiting in a UI event handler for threads to complete something.